# How to handle authorization status not determined for first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, alauthorizationstatus

**Utilities.m**

```
+(AVAuthorizationStatus)getAuthorizationStatus {
    NSString *mediaType = AVMediaTypeAudio;
    __block AVAuthorizationStatus AuthStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:mediaType];
    if(AuthStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:mediaType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
            AuthStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:mediaType];
        }];
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",AuthStatus);
    return AuthStatus;
}

+(ALAuthorizationStatus)getALAssetAuthorizationStatus {
    ALAssetsLibrary *aLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];

    ALAuthorizationStatus alAuthStatus;

    [aLib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:nil failureBlock:nil];

    alAuthStatus = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

    NSLog(@"Status=>%d", [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]);

    return alAuthStatus;
}
```

In my utilities class I wrote these two methods and there purpose is just to tell what is the authorization status.

These method will work fine if user have already `allowed` or `denied` the permission, but for first time these methods ask user for permission and the authorization status is `not determined`. In case of first time if user `allow` or `deny` I am not getting the updated authorization status. How to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your completion handler of requestAccessForMediaType, rather than re-calling authorizationStatusForMediaType, you just need to refer to the 'granted' boolean that's passed to the block (which you're not currently using).

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled across while looking for something related and figured I'd answer it for others who might find it.

Comment: But how can I retrieve just the status without prompting the user for a permission request? Executing `[AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:mediaType]` **always** returns `not determined`

Comment: If it's never been requested, then it's "undetermined", and if you don't want to prompt to find out, you can assume it's "no"